# Remove Bundler gem_task (v)tag prefix for git release tags

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler

Is it possible to configure Bundler's rake gem_tasks to not add the `v` prefix to git tags it creates for a gem release?

I am using `git-flow` which already tags the release without the `v`. So doing the release with `rake release` creates a duplicate tag for each release. I'd like to avoid this duplicate tag if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v` prefix is hardcoded (as of Bundler v1.4.0.pre.1). See https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.4.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb#L140

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey patch it easily enough

```
# Monkey patch the Bundler release class to strip the 'v'
# prefix from version tags
module Bundler
  class GemHelper
    def version_tag
      version
    end
  end
end
```

The code is here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb